# objective C deep link with regular Link

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an app that I want to be open with a specific link, from what I saw so far I need to add URL schemes with some uniq identifier witch will be present before the link.

so for example if in the URL schemes I put somthing like "asdf.asdf"
then when the link will be asdf.asdf://https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=objective%20C%20deep%20link%20with%20regular%20Link
it will open the app and I will get the link after it.

now my question is can I do it without it ? there is a QR code that when the user scan it transfer him to a web page, I want it to open the app if he has it, let say the link is this ( the link to this question ) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=objective%20C%20deep%20link%20with%20regular%20Link

how can I get my app to open if this link is scanned or clicked ? 
or there is no way it can be done and I need a special link for IOS to have this URL schemes before the link

Answer (score 0):

You can use normal hyperlinks with `http` or `https` but you will need to use [universal links](https://developer.apple.com/ios/universal-links/) to do that. Please review that documentation and post code that you have tried to solve the problem if you have more issues.  Hope that helps.

Comment: well, from what I see its from ios 9 and above and my code is from ios 7. so I understands that it cant be done, because I will need somthing like this to work: "abcd://https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=objective%20C%20deep%20link%20with%20regular%20Link" witch will not work on a web